# why there is 'None' print out in my python code

Tags: python

Hi: I am testing the recursive function like this:

```
def countdown(n):
    if n == 1:
        print 1
    elif n > 1:
        print countdown(n - 1), '\n', n
    else:
        pass
```

The function is to count down from $n$ to $1$. but why I get 'None' in the output?

```
In [2]: countdown(4)
1
None  
2
None 
3
None 
4
```

Thank you.

Comment: In order to solve this riddle, add some output before the place you suspect to generate the unexpected output and after. With that, circle in on the actual piece of code that causes the unexpected output. Using that technique, it should have been trivial to find that the second `print` outputs two lines, the first of which is `repr(None)`. Since the only thing in the first line is `countdown(n - 1)`, it would be obvious that printing the output of that function prints "None".

Answer (score 4):

When the function completes without returning anything, it implicitly returns `None`. Your function has no `return` statement, so `print countdown(n-1)` will print `None`.

Comment: The `None`s are coming from the `print` statement in the function, not the interpreter.  At least the ones shown in the question.

Answer (score 3):

You are printing what `countdown` returns, but it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2):

Your recursive function has no `return` statement. Because functions always *must* return something, the default is to return `None`.

Remove the `print` statement from the recursive function call, and put it on a separate line:

```
elif n > 1:
    countdown(n - 1)
    print n
```

Note that the `else: pass` block is entirely redundant. You can omit that part, you don't *have* to have an `else` statement.